# Prevent batch file from closing after it executes an external .exe program

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Believe it or not, I've searched all over stackoverflow and Google and can't find an answer to this that works for me.

(Windows 7 64-bit) I'm trying to create a batch file that runs multiple programs, one at a time. Simple, right? It works great until it runs the first `.exe` program. After the GUI of the `.exe` program closes, the batch file/cmd window also closes. I don't want it to close; I want the rest of the batch file to run.

Inside the batch file, I've tried the following methods, but none of them prevent the batch file from closing:

1. `Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
2. `Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`
3. `call Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`
4. `start Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`
5. `start "" /wait Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`
6. `start "" /w Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`
7. `start "" /w /b Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`
   `pause`

Does anyone know another method I can try? Maybe I should just call a powershell command or even translate the whole batch file to powershell, but I was trying to avoid powershell so that this script would work on multiple versions of Windows.

#### EDIT

I should also mention that with the methods above, the script closes *before* the `pause` command can be executed.

#### EDIT

Here's the full script with the rest of the `.exe` programs:

```
:Git
@echo off
(
echo.
echo.
echo DOWNLOADING GIT...
)
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe', 'Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe')"
(
echo.
echo.
echo LAUNCHING GIT INSTALLATION PROGRAM...
echo.
echo !IMPORTANT! WHEN YOU REACH THE SCREEN 'Adjusting your PATH environment',
echo SELECT 'Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt'.
echo KEEP ALL OTHER OPTIONS AT THE DEFAULT SETTING.
echo.
echo AFTER READING THE INSTRUCTIONS ABOVE, PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE
)
pause
Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe
pause
GOTO CheckOS

:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:32BIT
(
echo.
echo.
echo 32 BIT
echo.
echo DOWNLOADING TORTOISEHG (MERCURIAL)...
)
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-3.2.4-x86.msi', 'tortoisehg-3.2.4-x86.msi')"
(
echo.
echo.
echo LAUNCHING TORTOISEHG INSTALLATION PROGRAM...
)
tortoisehg-3.2.4-x86.msi
GOTO MingW

:64BIT
(
echo.
echo.
echo 64 BIT
echo.
echo DOWNLOADING TORTOISEHG (MERCURIAL)...
)
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-3.2.4-x64.msi', 'tortoisehg-3.2.4-x64.msi')"
(
echo.
echo.
echo LAUNCHING TORTOISEHG INSTALLATION PROGRAM...
)
tortoisehg-3.2.4-x64.msi
GOTO MingW

:MingW
(
echo.
echo.
echo DOWNLOADING MINGW...
)
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingwbuilds/mingw-builds-install/mingw-builds-install.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fmingwbuilds%2F%3Fsource%3Dtyp_redirect&ts=1422376004&use_mirror=iweb', 'mingw-builds-install.exe')"
(
echo.
echo.
echo LAUNCHING MINGW INSTALLATION PROGRAM...
)
mingw-builds-install.exe
(
echo.
echo.
echo DONE! PRESS ANY KEY TO CLOSE.
)
pause
GOTO END

:END
```

For the lines that run the external `.exe` program, I've tried all 7 forms of the command that were listed at the beginning of this question, yet the script always closes before reaching the next `pause` command. I've also tried using `cmd.exe /c` and `cmd.exe /k` from the suggestions below, but unfortunately the script still quits before reaching the `pause` command.

#### EDIT

<s>I figured out the problem (though not how to fix it). If I remove these lines:</s>

```
GOTO CheckOS

:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:32BIT
```

so that the following commands are under the same batch label, it works! But I'm not sure why including the `:CheckOS` label causes it to break. I've used this label in other batch scripts before, and they worked fine.

Nevermind, sorry. :S This only worked if the program had already been run. If it had already been run, a "modify, repair, or remove" screen popped up instead of an "install" screen. Apparently only the "install" screen closes the `cmd.exe` window.

#### FINAL EDIT

The parentheses were the problem. After removing them, everything else worked. Method number 1 at the beginning of this question works after removing the parentheses.

Comment: Do the ones with `pause` actually get to the "Press any key" prompt, or do they just exit without pausing? Because in those two-line snippets, the script is closing after the pause because the script is out of code. If you want to keep the command prompt open, you need to run it from the prompt instead of double-clicking the file.

Comment: No, they do not get to the `pause` command. I was hoping to be able to run this script by double-clicking it instead of using command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the executable in a new shell:

```
@echo off
cmd.exe /c Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe
echo Still here.
```

The /c switch tells the (new) shell to close when the program terminates. Execution of the batch script will be suspended until then.

For example:

```
@echo off
echo New window.
cmd.exe /c %WINDIR%\system32\notepad.exe
echo Window still open.
cmd.exe /c %WINDIR%\system32\notepad.exe
echo Window closed. You won't see this.
```

Comment: If he runs the script by double-clicking it, the initial window is still going to close at the end of the script.

Comment: `SomethingDark` was right; it still closes unfortunately.

Comment: You might try replacing `/c` with `/k`, which _should_ keep the newly-opened window open.

Comment: If your goal is to run multiple commands and then close the script window, the above will work fine. The script will not terminate after the first command. Note that using `/k` will open/leave a new window, not the one executing your batch script.

Comment: The `/k` switch does keep the command prompt window open after the `.exe`'s GUI closes, but it also terminates the script. There are more programs that I'd like to install in the script. Also, when using either of the `/c` and `/k` switches, a new command prompt window does not pop up, though maybe it just isn't displayed?

Comment: Are you displaying any information after all of the programs have executed? If you just want to run several commands in sequence, just use multiple `cmd.exe /c` or `start /wait` invocations.

Comment: If you want to install more programs in the script, just add them to the script. What you have shown us so far is terminating because the script is out of code to run, so it terminates.

Comment: I'll post my full script in my question.

Comment: Remove the parentheses surrounding the various `echo` statement blocks, e.g. immediately beneath the `:32BIT` and `:64BIT` labels.

Comment: You have a lot of parens that you don't need. so the parens within the parenthesized blocks that are not quoted need to be escaped with a ^ if you insist on leaving them all in there. I suggest removing the outer ones that are not needed.

Comment: Hey removing the parentheses worked! (I had them in there originally before I learned about the `@echo off` command.)